# HTML: Missing image resource has strange effect on ToolTip

Tags: html

I hope someone can help me since I have no clue whats going on here.
I have a table with an image in each row (at the beginning).
Each image has tooltip (title attibute). HTML looks lie this:

```
<td align="center"> 
<input type="hidden" value="0" />
<img src="/img/prognosis/2green.png" title="Augsburg-Göggingen ">   
</td>
```

To make the table sortable I  added a hidden input with a value, that is the criteria for sorting.

Everything looks fine until I delete the .png file.
Then it looks like this:

[image]

The grey rectangle's width is dependant on the tooltip's length.
How can this happen? 
Any help appreciated! THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange, what OS / browser are you using?
A valid image should have an `alt` attribute, like `<img src="img.png" alt="" />`.
It looks like you're using XHTML, but your img tag is not properly closed.

Comment: Thanks! I added the alt tag, now it looks correct.

<img src="/img/prognosis/2green.png" alt="green" title="Augsburg-Göggingen " />

But more important, I ended the img tag. That took effect on the rectangle! it's gone now!
Thanks"

Comment: Sorry, to correct myself: The alt attribute chenged it, not the img tag ending. Good hint nontheless!